# datepicker in dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Any help is appreciated.

I'm new to Dynamic Data. I want to users be able use datepicker when filling date fields. I have a date picker component which is a dll file. How can I use it in Dynamic Data?

Answer (score 0):

which dll are you using?
I used the AjaxControlToolkit.dll in my project. when you register this file, you get an option to "Add Extender" on every textbox you add to your page among which there is datepicker extension..
alternatively you can use jquery... to check this out, you may visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: How I can do it using jqueryui?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Dynamic Data Filter (called something like "DatePickerFilter") which implements the datepicker of you choice : (jQUery, Ajax, asp.net, etc.)
Then apply metadata on the column to reference that filter like so

```
[FilterUIHint("DatePickerFilter")]        
[Display(Name = "Date of Enrollment", AutoGenerateField = true, AutoGenerateFilter = true)]
public object EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
```